# Selenium - Clicks only the first row except every row by order

Tags: python, selenium

I want to right click on each one of the rows and than select "open in new tab". It works only for the first row, but not on the others. I can see that the code selecting each "tr" tag in the table and it looks fine, but the right click works only on the first row, why?

```
    def EstateNumber(self):
     bot = self.bot
     actionchains = ActionChains(bot)
     tds = bot.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[starts-with(., '0000')]")
     for row in tds:
        actionchains.context_click(row).perform()
        pyautogui.typewrite(['down','enter'])
```

The full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import pyautogui

class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
       self.bot = webdriver.Firefox()


def Enterweb(self):
    bot = self.bot
    bot.get('http://registers.maryland.gov/main/search.html')
    time.sleep(3)

def IAgree(self):
    bot = self.bot
    bot.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)')
    time.sleep(3)
    bot.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='I Agree To The Terms And Conditions']").click()

def EstateSearch(self):
    bot = self.bot
    bot.find_element_by_id('cboStatus').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    bot.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='OPEN']").click()
    bot.find_element_by_id('cboType').click()
    bot.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='FP']").click()

def Dates(self, date1, date2):
    self.date1 = date1
    self.date2 = date2
    bot = self.bot
    bot.find_element_by_id('DateOfFilingFrom').click()
    start = bot.find_element_by_id('DateOfFilingFrom')
    start.send_keys(self.date1)
    time.sleep(3)
    bot.find_element_by_id('DateOfFilingFrom').click()
    bot.find_element_by_id('DateOfFilingTo').click()
    to = bot.find_element_by_id('DateOfFilingTo')
    to.send_keys(self.date2)
    time.sleep(3)
    bot.find_element_by_id('DateOfFilingTo').click()
    to.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(1)
    to.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(3)


def EstateNumber(self):
     bot = self.bot
     actionchains = ActionChains(bot)
     tds = bot.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[starts-with(., '0000')]")
     for row in tds:
        actionchains.context_click(row).perform()
        pyautogui.typewrite(['down','enter'])


Website = Bot()

Website.Enterweb()
Website.IAgree()
Website.EstateSearch()
Website.Dates('01/01/2019','11/25/2019')
Website.EstateNumber()
```

I'm new in python and this is my first scraper. I'm trying to open a website, fill up the relevant choices from drop down menu what will open a table. From this table I want be able right click on each one of the rows and open them in new tab.

Comment: Do you Get any error messages? Does the tab open in the background or the foreground. You may need to switch back to the correct tab if the new tab opens in the foreground

Comment: I don't get any error messages. The links open on the background, many of them, but for the same row (the first one).
Basically it opens the first row in new tab many times.

Comment: You could try to open them using javascript, 
`for row in tds:
    url = row.get_attribure("href")
    driver.execute_script("window.open(url,'_blank');")`

Comment: Sorry i see there is a typi in my previos code, and you should use an fstring as well; `for row in tds: url = row.get_attribute("href") driver.execute_script(f"window.open({url},'_blank');")` if its still just the same link youll have to debug your selector, to see if its actally selecting what you need

Comment: Thank you! It worked - I just needed to be more specific with the xpath, it didn't get the attribute, so I changed to:
tds = bot.find_elements_by_xpath("//td/a")
         for row in tds:
             url = row.get_attribute("href")